# How to get background image of the first div with a specified class using jquery?

Tags: jquery

How do I get the first "grid_5" class div background image url? (eg: test1.jpg in the following example)

```
<div>
<div class="grid_5" style="background: url("test1.jpg");">
<div class="grid_5" style="background: url("test2.jpg");">
<div class="grid_5" style="background: url("test3.jpg");">
</div>
```

I tried the following but it doesnt work:

```
$('.grid_5:first').attr('background')
$('.grid_5')[0].attr('background')
```

Please tell me why is that and what should be the correct code for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.grid_5:eq(0)').css('background');
```

Comment: Why not `$('.grid_5')[0].css('background');`?

Comment: just trying to narrow down the selector as much as possible, and i dont need the other n-1 matches. do i have a proof that eq is much faster? unfortunately no, but maybe i should investigate

Answer (score 0):

You want `.css('background')`.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the style attribute to background-image, it should work just fine, as seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/KKRTz/

```
<div>
<div class="grid_5" style="background-image: url('test1.jpg');">
<div class="grid_5" style="background-image: url('test2.jpg');">
<div class="grid_5" style="background-image: url('test3.jpg');">
</div>

$('.grid_5').first().css('background-image');
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this style

```
 $('.grid_5:first').css('background')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Using the code above, it returns "url("test1.jpg")" is there a way to make it return "test1.jpg" only?

Comment: sorry i meant .css('background');